# Switch ON/OFF only Flash in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to use the phone's camera flash to be used a torch. I have a button that toggles between ON and OFF but for some reason the below code is not working. I know there are couple of questions already on this but none of them are giving correct answers.

Can somebody help me out?

Code to ON/OFF flash:

```
    camera = Camera.open();
    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

    flashon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            if (isFlashOn) 
            {
                Log.e("Flash", "Flash is turned off!");
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);                    
                isFlashOn = false;
                flashon.setText("Flash ON");
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.i("Flash", "Flash is turned on!");
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);                    
                isFlashOn = true;
                flashon.setText("Flash OFF");
            }
        }
    });
```

The following are the manifest details:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

Awaiting your response!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do it this way?
Maybe you have a problem because you are setting p as final.

```
camera = Camera.open();
flashon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        if (isFlashOn) 
        {
            Log.e("Flash", "Flash is turned off!");
            camera.setParameters(camera.getParameters().setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF));                    
            isFlashOn = false;
            flashon.setText("Flash ON");
        }
        else 
        {
            Log.i("Flash", "Flash is turned on!");
            camera.setParameters(camera.getParameters().setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH));                     
            isFlashOn = true;
            flashon.setText("Flash OFF");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I get error: 

The method setParameters(Camera.Parameters) in the type Camera is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code. This works for me.

```
private Camera camera;
private Parameters p;

//initialize camera instance
private void initCamera() {
    try{
        camera = Camera.open();
        p=camera.getParameters();
    }catch (Exception e){
        camera = null;
    }
}
//start flashing 
private void startFlashing() {
    initCamera();
    if(camera!=null && this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH); 
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.startPreview();           
    }
```